# How to run three thread with runMultipleAsyncTask in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have three AsyncTask. I want to run three thread Simultaneous.
I run two Asynctask Simultaneous with under code :

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void runMultipleAsyncTask(int id) {
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (id == encrypt) {

        Encryptedd asyncTask_encrypt = new Encryptedd();
        Progressdialogg asyncTask_progress = new Progressdialogg(asyncTask_encrypt);
        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            asyncTask_encrypt.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        } else {
            asyncTask_encrypt.execute();
        }
        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            asyncTask_progress.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        } else {
            asyncTask_progress.execute();
        }
    }
    if (id == decrypt){
        Decryptedd asyncTask2 = new Decryptedd();
        Progressdialogg asyncTask = new Progressdialogg(asyncTask2);
        if (currentapiVersion >=
                android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            asyncTask2.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        } else {
            asyncTask2.execute();
        }
        if (currentapiVersion >=
                android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        } else {
            asyncTask.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

how to run three thread with runMultipleAsyncTask in android studio?